# Where to put a sharepoint 2010 custom xsl

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I've created an xsl transformation for a list; I'm restricted to a client side solution: that is no packages, or visual studio; everything has to be developed and deployed via SharePoint Designer.

My Question is simple, what location does it make the most sense to store the xsl file(s) and why? Colleagues have been putting in the MasterPage Gallery, but when I asked why, I couldn't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Well what I've gone with is to create a Transformations Folder within the _catalogs library, the logic is that i don't want to expose the xslt to users that don't have access to Designer (PowerUsers). this gives me a central repository for xslt files where both front end (Designer) and back end (studio) have access to, but abstracts it from power users (web interface). 

My only other thought was to put them in the style library, but then decided against it for the purpose of abstraction from powerusers.